How to interact with matplotlib chart in PyCharm?
I want to see in PyCharm good old matplotlib window with options. I mean buttons on the bottom. They let me zoom chart and move from one part to another.


These navigation bottoms are very usefull, I need them.
But in PyCharm such chart is just a png picture without interactive options:

I cannot travel through it.
How to create chart with bottoms, so I can interact with it?
Code example (my question concerns all charts built with matplotlib, so code doesn't matter: any code):
# Plotting the chart
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.plot(res_df['aspect'], res_df['result'], label='Result')
plt.xlabel('Aspect')
plt.ylabel('Result')
plt.title('Result vs. Aspect')
plt.legend()
plt.xticks([0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()


Does this answer your question? How to get interactive plot of pyplot when using pycharm
